# Find the power series of rational function

Tags: power-series, generating-functions

How to find the power series of rational functions of type, e.g.
$$\frac{1}{1-6x+12x^2},\frac{6x}{1-6x+12x^2}$$

where denominator can't be factorized over the real domain.

Is there a way to use the method of undetermined coefficients (by completing the square), or is it necessary to use complex domain and trigonometry?

Comment: You can expand as $1/(1-(6x-12x^2))$ (using $1/(1-t)$) but this will be tedious. $1+6x+24x^2+72x^3+144x^4+\cdots$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach based upon the *[geometric series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)* (see the comment from @YvesDaoust).

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{1-6x+12x^2}&=\frac{1}{1-6x(1-2x)}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (6x)^k(1-2x)^k\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (6x)^k\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}(-2x)^j\\
> &=1+6x+24x^2+72x^3+144x^4\\
> &\qquad+\color{grey}{0}x^5-1728x^6-10368x^7-41472x^8-\cdots
> \end{align*}

It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^n]$ to extract the coefficient of $x^n$.

> We get
>   \begin{align*}
> [x^n]\frac{1}{1-6x+12x^2}&=[x^n]\sum_{k=0}^\infty (6x)^k\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}(-2x)^j\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n6^k[x^{n-k}]\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}(-2x)^j\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n6^k\binom{k}{n-k}(-2)^{n-k}\\
> &=(-2)^n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{k}{n-k}(-3)^k\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
>   and find this way a summation formula for the coefficient of the power series.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and the rule $[x^p]x^qA(x)=[x^{p-q}]A(x)$.
- In (2) we select the coefficient of $x^{n-k}$.

> *Note:* Since the zeros of $f(x)=1-6x+12x^2$ are non-real, we don't expect to get a closed formula of the binomial sum formula in real numbers only. In fact the following is valid (see e.g. formula 1.70 in *[this paper](http://www.dsi.dsi.unifi.it/~resp/GouldBK.pdf)* by R. Sprugnoli).
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n-k}{k}z^k
> =\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4z}}
> \left(\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4z}}{2}\right)^{n+1}-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1+4z}}{2}\right)^{n+1}\right)
> \end{align*}
>   Replacing the index $k$ with $n-k$ gives
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{k}{n-k}z^{n-k}
> =\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4z}}
> \left(\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4z}}{2}\right)^{n+1}-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1+4z}}{2}\right)^{n+1}\right)
> \end{align*}
>
> This expression evaluated at $z=-\frac{1}{3}$ and multiplied with $(-2)^n$ gives the coefficient of the power series and we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> (-2)^n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{k}{n-k}(-3)^k
> =\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}
> \left(\left(1-\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^{n+1}-\left(1+\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^{n+1}\right)3^n
> \end{align*}